# Android : Keep httpclient running in background and communicate with activity when message recieved by httpclient

Tags: java, android, push, comet, cometd

Sorry for the overly long title, but I had no idea how to do it otherwise. I am working on an Android project in which I am trying to use a PUSH framework called [Cometd](https://www.cometd.org) . Now Cometd uses Bayuex API/specification for implementing PUSH services.

When you consider the a normal website part, where users login or server-side scalable asynchronous applications, then Cometd works simply awesome, no complains there. The problem we are facing is on the app front. There is no support or documentation available for the same.

After some efforts I was able to write code to use Cometd in an Android app, unfortunately it is buggy and unstable. I will describe the structure of how I have built it, describe the problem and show the code.

There are 2 major Activity classes, `ConversationActivity` and `ChatMessagesActivity`. In ConversationActivity, I start a `httpclient` and connect to the PUSH service by performing a handshake.

In the same class, there is a ClientSessionChannel listener which keeps listening for new messages. In the ConversationActivity class, I retrieve all the conversations from the server's database for logged in user. This is done, so user can decide with whom he/she wants to chat with.

Now, when a conversation is tapped, I open the chat-messages for those two users in another activity.

Now, don't forget that each new message arrives in a ClientSessionChannel Listener in ConversationActivity, and that is the reason why I have to maintain a communication link between ConversationActivity and ChatMessagesActivity, which is causing all sorts of unstability.

**Now, what I would like to do is to push the listener and httpclient in another thread/class/background, etc.** Once that is done, how to keep an open communication between chat-messages which are opened, so messages are updated. I hope the problem is clear. I will post the code now. Kindly have a look :

```
public class ConversationActivity extends ApplicationDrawerLoader {

    static Context context;
List<PrivateChannel> privateChannelList = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Long> groupAccountList = new ArrayList<>();

    List<String> pushPrivateChannelList = new ArrayList<>();

    ListView conversationsList;

    ConversationAdapter conversationAdapter;

 protected static volatile BayeuxClient client;
    private ChatListener chatListener = new ChatListener();

    HttpClient httpClient = StaticRestTemplate.getHttpClient();

    String defaultURL = StaticRestTemplate.baseURL + "/cometd";

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversations);

        context = this;


        try {
            httpClient.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (isOnline()) {
            new getConversationsForLoggedInUser(this).execute();

            ClientTransport clientTransport = new LongPollingTransport(null, httpClient);
            client = new BayeuxClient(defaultURL, clientTransport);
            client.putCookie(new HttpCookie("JSESSIONID", StaticRestTemplate.getJsessionid()));
            client.getChannel(Channel.META_HANDSHAKE).addListener(new InitializerListener());
            client.getChannel(Channel.META_CONNECT).addListener(new ConnectionListener());
            client.handshake();
            boolean success = client.waitFor(2000, BayeuxClient.State.CONNECTED);
            if (!success) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not connect to PUSH service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

 public class getConversationsForLoggedInUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ResponseEntity<PrivateChannel[]>> {

client.getChannel("/person/"+privateChannel.getPrivateChannelName()).subscribe(chatListener);

// Here I get all conversations for user and load them in ListView using adapter
}
  public void sendMessageToChatActivity(final String channelName, final Map<String,Object> outputData) {
        // Here send the message to Chat activity.
        Log.d("Msg",String.valueOf(outputData.toString()));
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ChatMessagesActivity.recieveUpdatedMessage(channelName, outputData);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void recieveMessageFromChatActivity(String channelName, Map<String, Object> inputData){
        //client.putCookie(new HttpCookie("JSESSIONID", StaticRestTemplate.getJsessionid()));
        client.getChannel(channelName).publish(inputData);

    }

    private void initialize() {

    }

    private void connectionEstablished() {
        System.err.printf("system: Connection to Server Opened%n");

    }

    private void connectionClosed() {
        System.err.printf("system: Connection to Server Closed%n");
    }

    private void connectionBroken() {
        System.err.printf("system: Connection to Server Broken%n");
    }

    private class InitializerListener implements ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel channel, Message message) {
            if (message.isSuccessful()) {
                initialize();
            }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectionListener implements ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener {
        private boolean wasConnected;
        private boolean connected;

        public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel channel, Message message) {
            if (client.isDisconnected()) {
                connected = false;
                connectionClosed();
                return;
            }
            wasConnected = connected;
            connected = message.isSuccessful();
            if (!wasConnected && connected) {
                connectionEstablished();
            } else if (wasConnected && !connected) {
                connectionBroken();
            }
        }
    }

// THe below method sends message to the ChatMessagesActivity.
   public class ChatListener implements ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener {
        public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel channel, Message message) {
            sendMessageToChatActivity(channel.toString(),message);
        }
    }
```

ChatMessagesActivity :

```
public class ChatMessagesActivity extends ApplicationDrawerLoader {
    Context context;

    public ListView chatList;

    protected static ChatMessagesAdapter chatMessagesAdapter = null;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_messages);

        chatList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chatList);
        context = this;

 sendMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// Here I send message to ConversationActivity, which in turn sends it via CometdD.
                    sendMessageToConversationsActivity("/service/person/" + String.valueOf(conversationId), outputData);
}


    public static void recieveUpdatedMessage(String channelName, Map<String, Object> input) {

// Here I recieve the new message and add it to adapter. 
                    HashMap<String, String> insertMap = new HashMap<>();
// Add data to hashmap and add it to adapter 
 chatMessagesAdapter.add(insertMap);
                    chatMessagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
 public void sendMessageToConversationsActivity(String channelName, Map<String, Object> output) {
        ConversationActivity.recieveMessageFromChatActivity(channelName, output);
    }

    public class getPrivateChatsForUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ResponseEntity<RestReplies[]>> {

        ChatMessagesActivity chatMessagesActivity = null;

        getPrivateChatsForUser(ChatMessagesActivity chatMessagesActivity) {
            this.chatMessagesActivity = chatMessagesActivity;

        }
// Here i get chat messages from network and load it in list-view using adapter.,


    public class ChatMessagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Adapter code to display, nothing fancy. 
}
}
```

I know the code seems a bit longer, but so is the problem. I would appreciate any help on this. I am no Android expert, but just trying to integrate it. Thank you. :-)

*Edit*

```
public class CometdService extends Service {

    protected static volatile BayeuxClient client;

    String defaultURL = StaticRestTemplate.baseURL + "/cometd";


    HttpClient httpClient = StaticRestTemplate.getHttpClient();

    private ChatListener chatListener = new ChatListener();


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {
            httpClient.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        ClientTransport clientTransport = new LongPollingTransport(null, httpClient);
        client = new BayeuxClient(defaultURL, clientTransport);
        client.putCookie(new HttpCookie("JSESSIONID", StaticRestTemplate.getJsessionid()));
        client.getChannel(Channel.META_HANDSHAKE).addListener(new InitializerListener());
        client.getChannel(Channel.META_CONNECT).addListener(new ConnectionListener());
        client.handshake();
        boolean success = client.waitFor(2000, BayeuxClient.State.CONNECTED);
        if (!success) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not connect to PUSH service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }

    private class InitializerListener implements ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel channel, Message message) {
            if (message.isSuccessful()) {
                initialize();
            }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectionListener implements ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener {
        private boolean wasConnected;
        private boolean connected;

        public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel channel, Message message) {
            if (client.isDisconnected()) {
                connected = false;
                connectionClosed();
                return;
            }
            wasConnected = connected;
            connected = message.isSuccessful();
            if (!wasConnected && connected) {
                connectionEstablished();
            } else if (wasConnected && !connected) {
                connectionBroken();
            }
        }
    }

    private void initialize() {

    }

    private void connectionEstablished() {
        System.err.printf("system: Connection to Server Opened%n");

    }

    private void connectionClosed() {
        System.err.printf("system: Connection to Server Closed%n");
    }

    private void connectionBroken() {
        System.err.printf("system: Connection to Server Broken%n");
    }

    public class ChatListener implements ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener {
        public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel channel, Message message) {
           // sendMessageToChatActivity(channel.toString(), message);
        }
    }
}
```

A newly created service, work in progress.

Comment: `In ConversationActivity, I start a httpclient and connect to the PUSH service by performing a handshake.` wrong, this is a `Service` that should start such a connection

Comment: @pskink : Okay, as csenga also mentioned, I should start httpclient inside a Service. Just one thing, should the ConnectionListener class be also inside the Service?

Comment: yes, and unlike other say dont use `BroadcastReceiver`s, read about "bound services" instead

Comment: @pskink : Okay, This will surely take some time for me to implement and I will perform edits with time. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: @pskink : I have created a new Service and put the connection and related code there. For the PUSH framework to be used, I have to subscribe to channels. Now the problem is, I have to use the BayeuxClient instantiation, but because that is moved to Service, I cannot subscribe to channels in ConversationActivity. Can you please check out the AsyncTask in ConversationActivity and the Service class I have added. Thank you.. :-)

Comment: so now read about / google for `local bound service` pattern, or if you have more time you could do a custom `Content Provider` more time spend at start, but it pays off

Comment: @pskink : Okay.. Thank you.. :-) I will check out Content Provider as well. Thanks.. :-)

Comment: custom `ContentProvider` works very well with `Loader`s framework, you would be surprised how easily you can make a client Activity using `Loader`s + `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) might help for the communication with the server.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that? Thank you.

Comment: Also, how can I push the httpclient and the messageListener, which keeps running in background in some other class. This way, even if the user is using some other functionality, I can show notifications.

Comment: You can just initialize everything in the service and have activities communicate with the service instead of with each other. For the communication with the service you can use broadcast receiver or an EventBus [link](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Answer (score 1):

I did not read your whole question as the title says very much, I would suggest you to use `BroadcastReceiver` for this purpose.

Steps:

1. Register a broadcast receiver in your activity.
2. Send broadcast message from your HTTPClient.

You can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). Apart from it you can read many simple tutorials online on how to work with them.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying I should register the ChatMessagesActivity for receiving a BroadCast and whenever there is a new message, I should send it via Broadcast? Won't the ConversationActivity die when I move to another one?

Comment: @WeareBorg Well, you can search how to register Broadcast Receiver programmatically. Then you can register it in any activity you want and unregister when it is no longer required.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Service.html) and start your `httpclient` there. For updating your Activties you should use [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and/or Activity's `onResume` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use service like below for running in background.

```
public class BackgorundService extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        new HttpCall().execute();
    }


    private class HttpCall extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String response = "";
            // DO the HttpConnection here
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            Intent in = new Intent();
            in.setAction("MyAction");
            in.putExtra("name", s);
            sendBroadcast(in);
        }
    }
```

}

Call the above service in your activity and register your static broadcast reciever.

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lesson);
    startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class));
    registerReceiver(new MyReceiver(),new IntentFilter("MyAction"));
}

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("MyAction")){
            String value = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
             // Response from the background service..
        }

    }
}
```

}